# Change black background strip on resizing Window

Tags: javafx

Everyone know that problem. If you quickly resize a JavaFX application some areas are painted black, because of the recalculation of the user interface.

In my opinion this looks really ugly when you have the default grey touched Caspian or Modena theme and a very heavy UI that takes a while to recalculate.

Here is my question: **Is it possible to change this color**?

Comment: I think in JavaFX 8 this is fixed? Is that right?

Comment: Nope, I got it in our application running Java 8u25, too.

Comment: I believe that this is something to do with the window manager, and not Java?

Comment: Yeah but on other UI Frameworks such as Qt you do not have such a ugly border.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);` and create your own border (Window frame).

The 'black' border will now be in the color of your last pixel on the edges.

Probably not a good solution when you are using the default styles but for heavily custom styled applications it's a good thing.

And maybe try to set the color of the Scene.